# Combine javascript objects from an array that contain almost similar key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains objects. The array looks like this:

```js
[
    {
        "number": "10a",
        "person": "Velvet"
    },
    {
        "number": "10b",
        "person": "Edna"
    },
    {
        "number": "11a",
        "person": "Shionne"
    },
    {
        "number": "11b",
        "person": "Aifread"
    },

]
```

I want to combine objects that have identical `number` property. For example, the first two objects have property `number: "10a"`, and `number: "10b"`. I want these to be combined such that the output becomes:

```js
{
    "10": {
       "person": ["Velvet", "Edna"]
    },
    "11": {
       "person": ["Shionne", "Aifread"]
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to do it as it seems too complicated for me. I also looked over stackoverflow but can't seem to find a similar problem, hence, my post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is `number` has fixed length 3? If not ,it will be difficult to define similar

Comment: @flyingfox, yep. The number has a fixed length of 3.

Comment: @Agida,I think this problem is worth answering

Comment: Can we reopen the problem? The suggested answer doesnt answer my probem. Thanks

Comment: Ther are plenty of articles and questions about array transformations.  Good articles is here https://medium.com/@jasminegump/javascript-array-manipulation-using-filter-map-and-reduce-methods-7e5be19efab3 What is your number format? always any number and one letter?

Comment: Then, you can follow the link which agida has posted

Comment: The number property always has "a" and "b" in it

Comment: Yep, I've been looking for similar posts for almost 3 hours now but still cant figure out. I dont really ask questions in stackoverflow unless I cant solve it on my own.

Comment: Your output is not clear either: do you want object or array?

Comment: @JanPfeifer, my bad. It's an object.

Comment: The duplicate is exactly what you need. You need to loop through the array and instead of using the prefix with `_` as the key, you need to use the `parseInt(obj.number)` as the key. Anyway I have reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the normalization for number is just to remove non numeric characters. If so, you can just iterate over the original array and process each element:

```js
var original = [
    {
        "number": "10a",
        "person": "Velvet"
    },
    {
        "number": "10b",
        "person": "Edna"
    },
    {
        "number": "11a",
        "person": "Shionne"
    },
    {
        "number": "11b",
        "person": "Aifread"
    },
];

const merged = {}
    
        original.forEach(item => {
            var normalizedKey = item.number.replaceAll( /\D/g, "" )
            if(!merged[normalizedKey]) merged[normalizedKey] = { person: []}
            merged[normalizedKey].person.push(item.person)
        })
        
        console.log({merged})
```

Comment: I knew there was a way to loop only once but I couldn't figure it out! This was the answer I am looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Parse number. Add object if missing and append name:

```
const result = {};
arr.forEach(o => {
    const nr = o.number.slice(0,2);
    result[nr] = result[nr] || {person:[]};
    result[nr].person.push(o.person);
});

console.log(result);
```